# PHP7 - The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

Can somebody help me with this error I'm getting?

> Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead

My original code:

```
$match[1] = preg_replace('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', 'strtoupper("\0")', strtolower(trim($match[1])));
```

So I tried it like this:

```
$match[1] = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e',
                    function ($matches) {
                        foreach ($matches as $match) {
                            return strtoupper($match);
                        }
                    },
                    strtolower(trim($match[1])));
```

But I'm still getting the same error:

> Warning: preg_replace_callback(): The /e modifier is no longer
>   supported, use preg_replace_callback instead

Comment: Your `e` modifier has no more sense in your `preg_replace_callback()` code. Remove it. Then a `return` in `foreach` will stop the loop at the first iteration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message is telling you to remove the `e` modifier that you've included in your new code.

```
/ (?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D]). / e
^ ^------Pattern-------^ ^ ^ ---- Modifiers
|                        |
 -------Delimiters-------
```

You need to remove the modifier, so `preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', ...)` should be `preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./' , ...)`.

As an aside, you aren't benefiting from using a `foreach` loop in your new code. The match will always be in the second item in the array. Here's an example without using a loop:

```
$inputString = 'foobazbar';

$result = preg_replace_callback('/^foo(.*)bar$/', function ($matches) {
     // $matches[0]: "foobazbar" 
     // $matches[1]: "baz" 
     return "foo" . strtoupper($matches[1]) . "bar";
}, $inputString);

// "fooBAZbar"
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: "The match will always be in the second item in the array." – it is the *first* (and only) array item, in the OP's case, since they're not using capturing groups.

Comment: @salathe, I don't follow. I see a pair of `()` in the OP? None of the code provided in the OP would make sense without a capture group (which is totally there).

Comment: The `(?<=...)` is a [lookbehind assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), not a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).